# How to connect android device instead of AVD with database

Tags: mongodb, android-studio, flutter, android-virtual-device

I want to connect my android device instead of AVD with database in android studio. I am using MongoDB Database in that project.

The following code I am using to connect the database and the code works fine in AVD :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mongo_dart/mongo_dart.dart';
import 'package:mongo_dart/mongo_dart.dart' as dart_mongo;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  var Username;
  void DataColl() async {
    Db db = new Db("mongodb://10.0.2.2:27017/people");
    await db.open();
    print('connected to database');
    DbCollection coll = db.collection("students");
    await coll.insert({"name": Username});
    var student = await coll.find().toList();
    print(student);
    await db.close();
  }
   
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(title: Text("login form")),
            body: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  child: TextField(
                    onChanged: (text){
                      Username = text;
                    },
                  )
                ),
    
                 RaisedButton(
                  color: Colors.deepOrange,
                  elevation: 1.0,
                  textColor: Colors.blue,
                  child: Text("Submit"),
                  onPressed: DataColl,
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

But now I want to use my device instead of AVD to run the same code, what can I do for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use LAN wifi ip address
use this command:
`C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin>mongod --bind_ip ip`
where ip is your LAN-Adaptor ip,
then mention this ip in your code, and connect your android device to wifi LAN, then try